# Jquery append() on inner div while expanding the outer div so that the inner div elements fits inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, append

I have div structure similar to this. I'm using jquery to append elements inside the div with the id append. However, the outer div doesn't expand automatically to fit the appended elements.

```
<div class="well" id='expand'>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- some other divs -->
    </div>
    <div id= "append">
    </div>
</div
```

I solved the issue by increasing the height of the outer div i.e.

```
 var div_height = $('#expand').height();
 $('#expand').css({"height":div_height + append_height})
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What CSS does the outer div has? If you share a jsfiddler would be great

Comment: no css just bootstrap  'well'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with pure CSS using `min-height` and `height:auto` which causes the `expand` DIV to adjust its height according to its content:

```
#expand{
    height:auto;
    min-height:50px;
    height:auto !important;  /* for IE as it does not support min-height */
}
```

Also add `height:auto !important;` to the child element for mobile support.

Comment: Okay it worked for my laptop device but doesn't work on my ipad, how can I make it mobile responsive?

Comment: should work fine on all devices. did you try to relaod the CSS by clearing cache?

Comment: yes, I cleared the cache. Also, tried clear:both as well but no luck.

Comment: what iOS version? and which browser?

Comment: Fixed it. It didn't require `clear:both` though. Had to apply `height:auto !important;` to the child div.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid #222;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
}

.parent .child {
  padding-right: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 33%;
}

.parent .child:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.parent .child .content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100%;
}

.parent .child:first-child .content {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">
      blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
      blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">Div 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">Div 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by

```
#expand{
height: auto;
clear: both;
}
```

Clear property erases any float values (left or right) within the div. This prevents the expansion of width of the outer div due to float property of inner div.
If you have any issue with the responsiveness, you could use some simple HTML :

```
<div class="well" id='expand'>
    <div class="container">
        <div><!-- content --></div>
        <br>
        <div><!-- content --></div>
    </div>
    <div id= "append">
    </div>
</div>
```

Adding line break tag ensures that the div moves to next line across all devices.